# Swift - Start & End .SCN animation on a specific frame

Tags: swift, scenekit

I have a `.SCN` file which has an animation & I'm trying to start it at a specific frame but for some reason setting the `Timing` -> `Start time` does not work It just starts from the beginning. How can I start & end it on a specific frame?

[image: example]

Comment: can you post your scene (or a simplified version thereof)?